# How to show $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x \sin 2x= 2 \sin x\left(3 \cos^2x-1\right)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

> $$\frac{d}{dx}\sin x \sin2x= 2 \sin x\left(3 \cos^2x-1\right)$$

Could you please show me the steps to do this? Like what steps should I use?

Comment: What are you asking? Try to start the question and then we can hint to you what to do next etc.

Comment: Step 1: Read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Step 2: Ask a good question.  That includes formatting of formulas using mathjax, and (important) include what you have done so far.

Comment: How is the differentiation of sinxsin2x is 2sinx(3cos^2x-1)?

Comment: And what have you tried so far to get there?

Comment: @PradiptaDebnath Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It will make your expressions much more readable and clean.

Comment: I tried to put your formulas into MathJax but not knowing what you meant, I didn't do it well, so I put it back as you had it. Maybe someone else can format it better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By product rule $(sin\: x \: sin \: 2x)'=cos \:x \:sin\:2x+2sinx\:cos2x=2cos^2x \:sin\:x+2sin \:x \:cos \:2x=2sin\:x(cos^2\:x+2cos^2x-1)=2sin\:x(3cos^2x-1)$